# How to add a specific file to Firewall Exceptions list?

Tags: macos, terminal, firewall

I have to add `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm` to the exception list. I tried to find  and edit `com.apple.sharing.firewall.plist` but I didn't found such file anywhere. How can I manually add a specific executable to the exception list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so I'll attempt an answer...

I wanted to comment since I'd like to clarify why you need to add npm - my install of npm (via homebrew) works OK, without poking a hole in the firewall. Obviously YMMV...! But be aware I've *not* properly tested this with npm (I tested adding npm, and it continued to work fine.)

I believe you want the [application layer firewall](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/command-line-alf-on-mac-os-x/). (It's the same firewall you can also access through System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall).

My socketfilterfw's API appears to have changed from the one discussed in the linked article. I'd suggest caution, and that you check what the API is for your version *before* doing anything else:

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw -h
```

My version of socketfilterfw doesn't have the "-t" option mentioned in the linked article so I had to use:

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --add /usr/local/bin/npm
```

Comment: If you get "The file path you specified is invalid", then try chmodding the file to add execute permissions.